# How to group 50 columns for every row in sas and create a new column for their values?

Tags: python, excel, group-by, sas, transpose

I have 50 categorical columns which contain numbers and 1 separate column for a unique identifier and 100 rows. I want to create a new dataset out of it which would have 3 columns: Column1 for the unique identifiers; Column2 for the categorical columns grouped for each row; and, Column3 for the numerical values.

Currently, I have this:

```
ID  Column1 Column2..........Column 50
--- ------- -------          ---------
A     23      40                90
B     50      7                 79
C     0       9                 4
```

I want this,

```
ID   GroupedColumn   Value
---   -----------    -----
 A      Column1        23
        Column2        40
          .
         .
      Column50       90
B      Column1        50
       Column2        7
       .
       .
      Column50       79
C     Column1        0
      Column2        0
       . 
       .
      Column50       4
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with `python`?

Comment: Always add what you have tried, what research you've done on how to do it that (especially stuff that hasn't worked), any code you've done, what you want to happen and what is currently happening.

Comment: I am open to any language to make it happen (Python/SAS). It's a SAS dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use PROC TRANSPOSE.

```
proc transpose data=have out=want ;
  by id;
run;
```

The automatic variable `_NAME_` will have the original variable name and the values will be in a variable named `COL1`.  You can use options on the PROC TRANSPOSE statement to change the default names.

```
proc transpose name=GroupedColumn prefix=Value out=want;
```

Note that the name will still have `1` appended for the first observation per ID. If you have multiple observations per ID then you will also get VALUE2, VALUE3, etc.

Or use the `rename=` dataset option on the output dataset to change the names of the new variables.

```
proc transpose name=GroupedColumn out=want(rename=(col1=Value));
```

Comment: Can you show how `Proc DATASETS` would be used to remove or change the default label of column `_NAME_` ?

Comment: If you want to use PROC DATASETS then use the MODIFY and RENAME statement.  But you can just create the dataset originally with the names you want so no need for a separate step.

Comment: Two edge things about transpose that annoy me.  1) there is no option for changing the label of the output _name_ role variable, it is always "NAME OF FORMER VARIABLE" 2) there is no ROWWISE option for the case of data that may not have unique by groups rowwise.

Answer (score 0):

You can re-LABEL the *name* role variable if you are willing to use a little trick.

```
proc transpose data=sashelp.class out=test;
   by name;
   var _all_;
   attrib _name_: label='This is how';
   run;
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Proc transpose may be able to help you.